# Use accelerated graphics on Windows 10 Linux subsystem with Xming?

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opengl, xming

I've got `Ubuntu 16.04` running in `Windows 10 16251.0` as a Linux subsystem, and I've got `Xming-mesa 6.9.0.31` installed.

I launch Xming using `Xming :0 -multiwindow -clipboard`

Then in my Ubuntu bash shell I type `export DISPLAY=:0` and I can launch graphical applications in Xming.

However, I do not get accelerated graphics, so when I launch an editor (e.g. `sudo spyder3`), I have to deal with the jerky scrolling and such that you get without acceleration.

How do I fix this? I'm sure my video card (AMD RX480 latest drivers) supports OpenGL, but for some reason I'm not activating it correctly.

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1487555/how-to-troubleshoot-opengl-on-ubuntu-under-windows-10-wsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` in WSL to force rendering to happen on the Windows side of things.

Comment: `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` 
`export DISPLAY=:0` 
`sudo spyder3`

No change :(

Comment: @geofurb What if you try it with `glxgears`?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: `glxgears` isn't realted to `spyder3`, I want you to see if `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` impacts `glxgears`.

Comment: ~1300FPS, but it jolts every so often. (Unless that's part of the intended behavior?)

Comment: What's the difference when `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` is and isn't set.

Comment: Similar performance after executing `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0`

Comment: Did you unset `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` before running it the first time?

Comment: Negative; confirmed with `export -p` that `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` was set for the first run and unset for the second run.

Comment: I don't know, then. Sorry.

Comment: What's the reasoning there?

Comment: @geofurb Oh I just remembered, it's an option in XMing as well, or at least VcXsrv has it.

Comment: So setting LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0 doesn't refert the framerate from glxgears to software accelerated speeds; HOWEVER, rebooting the machine restores it to software acceleration, and you get ~60fps instead of ~1300fps. What's going on that Spyder isn't benefiting from this graphical acceleration?

Comment: Would XDMCP offer better performance or worse, since I'm rendering on the Windows computer?

Comment: When I use this with `-wgl` it makes glxgears far slower. The only smooth animation is no `-wgl` and no `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT`.

Comment: @user541686 I had to do the same. See this related question for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/1487555/how-to-troubleshoot-opengl-on-ubuntu-under-windows-10-wsl