# openGL version mismatch

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, opengl

Currently working to install gym/roboschool, running into the following error from WSL:

[image]

The latest drivers are installed on my GPU which states I'm on OpenGL 4.6.

EDIT

Still no luck unfortunately, I'm on 20H1 now (after weeks of failing to install) confirmed on wsl2, updated graphics drivers, but somehow ubuntu isn't using my graphics properly. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh9FX.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use accelerated graphics on Windows 10 Linux subsystem with Xming?](https://superuser.com/questions/1238925/use-accelerated-graphics-on-windows-10-linux-subsystem-with-xming)

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Use `winver` to provide this required information.  What WSL instance do you have installed?  What version of that instance are you using?  How did you determine your hardware supports OpenGL?  Did you determine that within a Windows command prompt or a WSL command prompt?  You did install the display drivers within the WSL instance, if you did, there might be one work around that could work.

Comment: It may be related to that topic actually, the solution there doesn't seem to help though. I'm on windows version 1809, Nvidia 1070TI graphics, running the Ubuntu windows store app and this is all running through that. Although I didn't install the drivers through the app, just normally through the nvidia windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

> The latest drivers are installed on my GPU which states I'm on OpenGL 4.6

Since OpenGL is highly dependent on device drivers.  I suspect your problem is due to the fact, the current version of Windows Subsystem for Linux, is unable to load kernel Linux drivers.  Since the current version of Windows Subsystem for Linux, does not officially support GUI Linux applications, this makes complete sense.

> The latest drivers are installed on my GPU which states I'm on OpenGL 4.6.

You might have necessary Windows drivers installed that does not mean they are accessible to the Windows Subsystem Linux instance.  Just because you have the Windows drivers installed allowing to run a Windows OpenGL executable does not mean you can run a Linux executable that requires a kernel driver[.](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/11)

The limitations I describe will be resolved with the release of [Windows Subsystem for Linux 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) which will appear in a future build planned for a June 2019 release.  WSL 2 will run an actual Linux kernel once it is released.

> WSL 2 uses an entirely new architecture that uses a real Linux kernel.  Initial builds of WSL 2 will be available through the Windows Insider program by the end of June 2019.  Linux binaries use system calls to perform many functions such as accessing files, requesting memory, creating processes, and more.

Strictly speaking.  If WSL 2 is running a Linux kernel then you should be able to install the required display drivers to provide OpenGL support.

Comment: There might be a workaround that works with WSL on Windows 10 version 1903.  I am waiting for more information from the author before I provide it.  Since the workaround involves installing vcXsrv, I consider my answer correct, it strictly isn't possible to run a Linux application with a GUI on the current version of the WSL.  Since you would technically be drawing the application GUI, within a Windows X instance, which would be entirely controlled by the Windows application.  I am still waiting for the information before I spend a majority of a day working out the solution.

Comment: Everything should be rendering on the windows side, I'm running xming which is successfully displaying other gui applications (but it's my first time with it, definitely possible I'm missing something there as well)

Really appreciate the help Ramhound!

Comment: @AmeenAl-Khafaji - The simplest solution is to just upgrade to the current Insider Preview build that has WSL 2.

Comment: Afraid no luck with this solution, current computer state is:  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -v NAME            STATE           VERSIONUbuntu-18.04    Running         2  winver output: Version 1903 (OS Build 18917.1000)

Nvidia (1070 Ti) Driver: 435.27

Comment: I am confused.  The only version of Windows 10 that I am aware that has WSL 2 currently is 20H1.  `18917.1000` is 19H2 (i.e. a 1903 cumaltive update).  Why are you providing this vital information in a comment?

Comment: Hmm interesting, strange that it tells me its on WSL 2, I'll get the fast release of windows insider and edit my post with any update

Comment: @AmeenAl-Khafaji - I know that WSL2 is suppose to be introduced with (19H2) but I didn't think they had added it to it.  I was only aware that 20H1 had it.